# PHP preg_match_all wont find values

Tags: php, xml-parsing, preg-match-all

I keep try to search for two values inside an string. I know I have to use the following command in PHP:

```
preg_match_all
```

It also have to be escaped. So I've tried to create a filter for this.

---

**Original code:**

```
<![CDATA[312.09999999999997]]></var><var n='destinationX' t='n'><![CDATA[510.75]]>
```

---

**My actual code:**

```
if (preg_match_all("\<!\[CDATA\[([0-9a-z_-]+)\]\]\>\</var\>\<var n=\'destinationY\' t=\'n\'\>\<\!\[CDATA\[([0-9a-z_-]+)\]\]/i>", $packets, $matches) )
```

---

Sadly it wont return the data contained in the `CDATA`. So I'm trying to get the following informations from this string:

Match 1: 312.09999999999997

Match 2: 510.75

---

Does anyone have a clue what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: will the CData always contain a decimal number?

Comment: yes the cdata should always contain cdata

Comment: And what if the XML creator decides to not use `CDATA` ?

Comment: are you trying to check if exist or capture ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$myString = "<![CDATA[312.09999999999997]]></var><var n='destinationX' t='n'><![CDATA[510.75]]>";
preg_match_all('/CDATA\[([a-z0-9-\.]+)\]/i', $myString, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 312.09999999999997
    [1] => 510.75
)
```

---

**LIVE DEMO**

http://ideone.com/C3a7Ci

Answer (score 2):

change your regular expression to this:

```
/<!\[CDATA\[([0-9a-z_\-.]+)\]\]>/
```

you need to escape a literal hyphen or the regex engine will assume it's looking for a range (like in 0-9 or a-z) and you didn't allow periods.

I put it in a quick test script using the string you supplied:

```
<?php

$matches;
$packets = "<![CDATA[312.09999999999997]]></var><var n='destinationX' t='n'><![CDATA[510.75]]>";
preg_match_all('/<!\[CDATA\[([0-9a-z_\-.]+)\]\]>/i', $packets, $matches);
$matches = $matches[1];
print_r($matches);
```

This gave me an output like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 312.09999999999997 [1] => 510.75 )
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get the values in between;

```
$packets = "<![CDATA[312.09999999999997]]></var><var n='destinationX' t='n'><![CDATA[510.75]]>";
$regex = "~[0-9]+\.[0-9]+~";
preg_match_all($regex, $packets, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Comment: This will also grab decimal values outside of the CDATA block, not sure if you intended for that

Comment: @iam-decoder Well, he's only showing one string, and asking us how to get the two values from the one string.